# Why routes to crud actions fail when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, crud

Im working on a rails project, trying to create admin area where you could see a list of all users, edit their details, etc.

I've added this to routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  scope "/admin" do
   resources :users
  end
```

in users_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

i've also got a index.html.haml file in views/users. its jsut one heading for now:

```
%h1 Users index
```

However, when i try to acess /admin/users it throws 404 page not found error.

I didn't configure devise for this app, and didn't work with devise much before. Where could the problem be?

**edit**

there is no error message, it just redirects to 404 instead of loading index.html.haml . console log:

```
Started GET "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-13 13:13:17 +0100
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  Rendered errors/error_404.html.haml within layouts/application (4.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_environment_notice.html.haml (3.4ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 670ms (Views: 632.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: type `rake routes` command in you terminal in application root and see what routes it gives for users/index

Comment: users GET    /admin/users(.:format)          users#index

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact error.

Comment: For consistency and future maintainability, I would recommend scoping the controller and the views to admin as well. In the controllers and views folders create an admin folder and namespace your admin users controller and views accordingly.

Comment: Pavan, theres no error, it just redirects to 404, i updated question with console log. Margo, I think I'll try to get index page loading first, before experimenting with more scoping